# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory and Not marking nodes down due to local pause of

Tags: java, cassandra

one of my cassandra node is running on an aws instance, some time it is getting stopped, I have seen the following info in the `system.log` and `cassandra.log` files.
What might be the reasons for these kind of errors

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
```

and

```
Not marking nodes down due to local pause of
```

How to solve these issues

Comment: Did you try to produce heapdump on OOME and analyze it? Also, which version of Cassandra do you use?

Comment: Cassandra version is 3.0.9 and how to produceheapdump on OOME ?

Comment: Check this documentation: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configHeapDump.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was installing Java 8 on all of the nodes and changing the GC strategy to G1, and the results were amazing.
I’ve launched all nodes with 8GB of heap with the G1 Garbage collection algorithm and I saw an immediate improvement, the heap used didn’t go past 4GB per node, and the GC times decreased.

I’ll explain the steps I took to change the setting to run with the G1GC and I’ll elaborate a bit on how everything works.

(After I finished writing this post, I saw that it was just too long, so I’ve decided to be nice and left  A lot of things  for the enrichment parts, so feel free to skip them)

Install the newest Oracle JDK 8 to have the latest update of the G1GC. This will also work with Java JRE / JDK later than Java 7 update 4, but  in the manner of  Apache Cassandra Java 8 is recommended.

Installing Java 8 (For Debian based systems):
Adding the Oracle repository, updating the local apt-get cache and installing oracle-java8-installer package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Automated installation (auto accept license)

```
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Setting “JAVA_HOME” variable in the environment:

```
sudo vim /etc/environment
```

Add these lines in the end of the file.

```
 JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"
 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Reload the newly added environment variables:

```
source /etc/environment
```

We now have the Java 8 JDK installed.

In order to setup the G1 algorithm to run on a specific node you’ll need to follow these steps:

1. In the `cassandra-env.sh` file add the follwing lines:

   ## G1 - Parameters

   `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC"
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5"
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal"`
2. You’ll need to comment out all of the CMS specific flags that will probably be there by default. search for these and be careful for others:

   `-XX:+UseParNewGC
   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
   -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
   -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
   -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
   -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
   -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
   -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
   -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`

And that’s it,

## just restart the node and you’ll be up and running!

Reference:-
http://progexc.blogspot.in/2015/12/taking-care-of-garbage-in-cassandra.html